# Import and Print Json objects in Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file which looks like the one shown in the picture.
How can I import and print all the Quantity and Rate in Pandas?
How can I print the sum of all the Quantity for Buy and Sell separately?
How can I print the sum of all the Quantity who's values is greater than x. For eg:SUM(Qty > 5)

[image]

In raw format, the data is like this

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"buy":[{"Quantity":199538.30948659,"Rate":0.00000970},{"Quantity":62142.31715449,"Rate":0.00000968},{"Quantity":233476.03486058,"Rate":0.00000967},{"Quantity":75613.30879931,"Rate":0.00000966},{"Quantity":3109.14961399,"Rate":0.00000965},{"Quantity":66.22406639,"Rate":0.00000964},{"Quantity":401.06420081,"Rate":0.00000963},{"Quantity":186.93339628,"Rate":0.00000961},{"Quantity":122731.01165366,"Rate":0.00000960},{"Quantity":7718.27750144,"Rate":0.00000959},{"Quantity":802.00000000,"Rate":0.00000958},{"Quantity":2050.72163419,"Rate":0.00000956},{"Quantity":1000.00000000,"Rate":0.00000955}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

#change 'buy' for other results
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json('file.json')['result']['buy'])

#for filtering
print(data.query('Quantity > 5').query('Rate > 0.00000966').sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas.read_json()` command to do this. Just pass it your json file in the function and pandas will create a dataframe out of it for you.

Here's the link to the documentation for it where you can pass extra parameters like `orient='records'` and so on to tell pandas on what to use as the dataframe columns and what to use as row data etc.

Here's the link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Once in the dataframe, then you can run various commands to calculate sums of quantity for buy and sell. Having the data in a dataframe makes life a bit more easier when running math calculations in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) and pass the meta path :

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

buy_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['result'],'buy')
#Similarly for sell data if you have a separte entity named `sell`. 
sell_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['result'],'sell')
```

Output:

```
   Quantity     Rate
0  199538.309487  0.00001
1   62142.317154  0.00001
2  233476.034861  0.00001
3   75613.308799  0.00001
4    3109.149614  0.00001
```

For sum you can do

```
buy_df['Quantity'].sum()
```

From now for selection and indexing the data refer this - [Indexing and Selecting Data - Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)